# Delphi change IOS StatusBar Color

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, colors, statusbar

Hey Guys i am developing with Delphi 10 Seattle. 
I am actually trying to change the status bar color on top of the Application. Cause when running my Application on my iphone the color of the status bar on top  the app looks really worse . So how do i change the status bar on ios in another color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'll understand your question correctly but have you tried to set:

**MyForm.Fill.Color** im the Object Inspector?

I was reading somewhere if you change the fill.color of the form the statusbar will change its color too... You can then at runtime change the Form.fill.color back to its initial state the color of the statusbar will not change...

Comment: No problem glad I could help